# SortDirection in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, sorting, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Where can I find SortDirection in .NET core?
In .NET Framework, We can find SortDirection in System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace.
I want to develop generic repository class using Entity Framework Core and I need dynamic sorting in order to get data from databse.
Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/sorting-data

Comment: Using something from `System.Web.UI.WebControls` in EF doesn't smell right to me anyway. I guess you could create you own. You need to call `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` respecfully.

Comment: Use [ListSortDirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.listsortdirection?view=netcore-3.1). Don't create a repository though, unless there are very *very* compelling reasons to do so.

Comment: I use Clean Architecture to develop my application. In Clean Architecture principles, you should keep layers completely separated from each others and the Business Logic Layer shouldn't depend on your data source or the way you chose to communicate to your data source. So I should use repository pattern to achieve this principle. Entity Framework Embedded Repository has some limitations. fore example if your data source changed from database to service, you can't use Entity framework and its built in repository.